# How to get the input field in nested div through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to get the input field which is in div using jquery .but I am unable to to get it. I want to iterate it with class model and add into the array of string and pass it to controller.

below is my one div that have class model i will make multiple div like this and iterate it to its to get the input field in it and pass it to my controller

```
   <div class="models">
            <div class="row" >

                <div class="col-md-12" >
                    <label class="control-label" >NIC</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="VNIC" id="VNIC" required>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="VfirstName" id="VfirstName" required>
                </div>
            </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
                $("#Visitor-form").on("submit", function () {
                    //Code: Action (like ajax...)
                    var slides = $(".models");
                    console.log(slides);
                    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {

                        var previsitor = [
                            { NIC: slides[0].value, V_Name: slides[0].value }
                        ];
                    }
                    previsitors = JSON.stringify({ 'previsitors': previsitor });
                    console.log(previsitors);
                    $.ajax({
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/PreVisitor/addMultipleVisitor',
                        data: previsitors,
                        success: function () {
                            $('#result').html('"Pass List<PreVisitor>" successfully called.');
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            $('#result').html(response);
                        }
                    });

                })
```

Comment: `$('.form-control')` since you have a class in your inputs

Comment: what i wanted is create different div with class model and iterate thorugh it and each div have different input type which make my single view model .. and I wanted to pass a list of viewmodel to controller

Comment: try [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this is what you need? Get all the input values and put them in an array.
Not sure which type of array you want, just values, or values to names.

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
     var total = [];
     var mapped = {};
     $('.models').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(index,elem){
        total.push(elem.value);
        mapped[elem.name] = elem.value;
     });
     console.log(total);
     console.log(mapped);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="models">
            <div class="row" >

                <div class="col-md-12" >
                    <label class="control-label" >NIC</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="VNIC" id="VNIC" required>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="VfirstName" id="VfirstName" required>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
<button>click me</button>
```